# Printing Ballot Box with and without check in java

Tags: java, string, unicode

I'm trying to create a todo task manager and one component is indicating on the GUI(Displays Strings in a window) whether the task is completed or not. I've tried printing out the unicode characters u2610 and u2610 to see what it is but it just prints out the usual box character ☐ to indicate that it's sort of invalid.

I've also tested out

```
System.out.println("\u2610");
System.out.println("\u2611");
```

to print out on the console and both print out "?". Is there anyway I can just convert a symbol into a string and print it properly without using any Swing function?

Comment: If you are using Windows, it's the problem of the Operating System, and not of Java. Windows simply doesn't understand what is going on. You can attempt to change the parameters of cmd.exe and the default font that it uses to resolve the issue, or change to some reasonable OS.

Comment: Ah that makes sense for the System calls. However is there anyway I can print out the unicode symbols stated above in a GUI? As I've said it prints out ☐. Is this also due to the OS?

Comment: No. Your program works, but the font that is used does not contain those characters.

Comment: As well as the default font being useless, the default code page doesn't contain the characters, and if your change the code page to 65001 (UTF-8-like) there are a load of bugs in the command prompt that break it. If you really need to get Unicode to the Windows console there is [JNA](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/java-unicode-on-windows-command-line.html) but it usually isn't worth the pain.

Comment: You'd have to do native calls to `WriteConsoleW` to print arbitrary Unicode characters. Otherwise you can go for the classics—`"[X]"` and `"[ ]"`.